# Rational point of a curve over function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective algebraic curve of genus greater than equal to $2$ and defined over a function field $K$ of a curve over $\mathbb C$. Is the set of $K$-rational points of $X$ nonempty?

Comment: Already $X(\mathbb{C})$ is nonempty, and $K$ contains $\mathbb{C}$ as field of constants, so… Is this really the question you meant to ask? (You could add “nonconstant”, but if $K = \mathbb{C}(Y)$ then you are asking about morphisms $Y\to X$, and nonconstant such don't always exist.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen by the notation X(K) i meant the set of K rational points of X

Comment: Why is $X(\mathbb{C})$ non-empty?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen $X(\mathbb C)$ is only well-defined if $X$ is defined over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: It is probably easy to construct counterexample over $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ by looking for curves which do not have points over some completion of $K$. E.g. consider $x^4+ty^4=t^2$ over $\mathbb{C}((t))$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread (I missed the words “defined over” in the question).

Comment: @RP_ Since the function field of every curve over $\mathbb C$ can be written as an extension of $\mathbb C(t)$ that embeds into $\mahbb C((t))$, the same example will work for every base curve.